# What web application vulnerabilites are most likey to be found in a source code review vs a grey box pentest?

Tags: web-application, appsec, source-code, code-review

What type of vulnerabilities would be found additional in a source code review vs a pentest?

If my organization performs regular grey box pentests, do we really require to perform source code reviews?

Comment: It's hard to say what types because it depends on the technology used and how it was written and yes there should always be code review

Comment: weak/misimplimented encryption, hard-coded passwords, sub-component vulnerabilities (think flash, activeX, pdf, msword, etc), buffer overflows, hidden API calls, hidden web-hosted folders not under a short+common name, improper type/error handling, specific detail-leaking error-page discovery, add all the normal CSRF, XSS, and other vulns.